C# Sqlite CommitAsync() does not save any changes to my table
i am writing a program to keep track of some uploads that I do on a blob storage. this is my method that takes as input a list of objects that basically contains some fileInfo information (name path date and so on)
public async Task UploadFilesAsync(List<FileMetadata> filesToUpload, CancellationToken token)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Starting upload of {filesToUpload.Count} files.");
    ErrorHandler.LogInformation($"Starting upload process for {filesToUpload.Count} files.");

    foreach (var file in filesToUpload)
    {
        using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(token);
        try
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // Fetch the file metadata and update the StartUploadDate
            var entity = await _context.FileMetadata.FindAsync(new object[] { file.Id }, token);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new Exception($"File not found in database: {file.FilePath}");
            }

            entity.StartUploadDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            entity.UploadStatus = "Uploading";
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(token);

            Debug.WriteLine($"Set StartUploadDate for file: {entity.FilePath}");

            // Perform the actual file upload
            var folderPath = await _context.FolderPaths.FirstOrDefaultAsync(fp => fp.Name == file.FolderName, token);
            if (folderPath == null)
            {
                throw new Exception($"FolderPath not found for {file.FolderName}");
            }

            string rootFolder = folderPath.Destination ?? "default";
            string subFolder = file.FileExtension.TrimStart('.').ToLower();
            string destinationFolder = Path.Combine("SURVEY_DATA", Settings.Default.SelectedVessel, rootFolder, subFolder);

            UploadResult uploadResult = await _uploadManager.UploadFileAsync(file.FilePath, "dotnetapp", destinationFolder, token);

            // Update the file metadata after upload
            entity.IsUploaded = uploadResult.IsSuccess ? 1 : 0;
            entity.UploadStatus = uploadResult.IsSuccess ? "Uploaded" : "Failed";
            entity.EndUploadDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (uploadResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                entity.BlobStoragePath = uploadResult.BlobStoragePath;
            }
            else
            {
                entity.ErrorMessage = uploadResult.Message;
                entity.ErrorCount++;
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(token);

            await transaction.CommitAsync(token);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Updated file status: {entity.FilePath}, Status: {entity.UploadStatus}");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            await HandleCancellationAsync(file, transaction, CancellationToken.None);
            return; // Exit the method after cancellation
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleErrorAsync(file, ex, transaction, token);
        }
    }

    Debug.WriteLine($"Finished upload process for {filesToUpload.Count} files.");
    ErrorHandler.LogInformation($"Completed upload process for {filesToUpload.Count} files.");
}

the problem is that even tho uploadResult is marked as Uploaded the code is failing to update the entry in my database table.

The code is deeply broken. There's asbolutely no need for an extra transaction. SaveChanges is only meant to be called once, at the very last moment, to commit all pending changes in a single, internal database transaction. A DbContext is a disconnected Unit-of-Work and detects all changes in the objects it tracks without keeping any connections open. When SaveChanges is called the DbContext will persist all changes, for all entities in the proper order and fix up relations, foreign keys and generated values

The extra transaction means that changes aren't visible to other connections until CommitAsync is called. In case of error, all changes will be rolled back, including the first INSERT INTO FileMetadata. Until the transaction commits no other connection will be able to see the pending upload record
